# Javascript + Maths - Get a bearing angle from a point A to B properly

Tags: javascript, math, 2d

Asking on the internet I found a formula to find the bearing angle from point A to point B, and let's say that for now it's half working.

```
//Creates to points A and B and set their coordinates
var A = {
    x : 250,
    y : 250
};

var B = {
    x : 100,
    y : 250
};

var angle = Math.acos(
              (A.y - B.y) / 
              Math.sqrt(
                  Math.pow(A.x - B.x, 2) + 
                  Math.pow(A.y - B.y, 2)
              ) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7js7e90k/4/

Right now the point B (GREEN DOT) is to the left of the point A (WHITE DOT), the angle shown should be 270°, but it shows 90°. And if you set the point B to the right (changing the object coordinates) you will see that it will also show 90°.

I need it to show the proper angle relative to the north (0°) but it wont go beyond 180°, something needs to change in the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Math.acos()` returns a value between 0 and π rather than between 0 and 2π, you can check if point A is to the left or right of point B and add an extra 180˚ if A is right of B.

Try this:

```
var ref_angle = Math.acos((A.y - B.y) / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(A.x - B.x, 2) + Math.pow(A.y - B.y, 2))) * (180 / Math.PI);

if (B.x >= A.x) {
    var angle = ref_angle
}
else {
    angle = ref_angle + 180
}
```

**UPDATED:**

If you want to avoid using the conditional, you will need to use `Math.atan2()`. However `Math.atan2()` measues the angle relative to the positive x-axis (east) and returns values between -180˚ and 180˚. I've modified the formula below get the angle relative to the positive y-axis (north) and to return values between 0˚ and 360˚:

```
var angle = ( ( ( -(Math.atan2((A.x-B.x),(A.y-B.y))*(180/Math.PI)) % 360) + 360) % 360);
```

Check out this **UPDATED** working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7shjjxq/5/

Comment: I like this, this is a good 'Hack', I wonder if there is an actual way to fix the formula.

Comment: @Juan Bonnett You're right, the use of conditionals is a bit of a 'hack'. Check out my updated formula and fiddle.

Comment: Working great! Let's use this!

Comment: Hehe, sorry, found a problem, but should be simple to solve. When B is to the left, it takes the south pole as the north pole, Check this fiddle, it should not be close to 180 but close to 360 https://jsfiddle.net/g7shjjxq/3/

Comment: It's like half of the orange gets inverted

Comment: WAIT. EDIT: I understand what's happening. With your last formula, the SOUTH pole is the 0 / 360 degree

Comment: Hehe, I'm sorry, your answer is perfect and I works fine, and I would love if it takes the north pole of A and counts the degrees Clockwise from 0 to 359. Like if the B point was a number in a clock.

Comment: @Juan Bonnett Ahh, I see. I didn't realize "bearing angle" is always measured clockwise. See the updated formula and fiddle!

Comment: A true hero. *salutes*

Answer (score 2):

you can compute that with atangent to avoid modulo or IFs, then convert to deg:

```
function getAngle (x1, y1, x2, y2){
    var dx = x2 - x1,
    dy = y2 - y1;
    return Math.atan2(dy,dx)*(180/Math.PI);    
}

var A = { x : 250,  y : 250};
var B = { x : 100,  y : 250};

getAngle(A.x, A.y, B.x, B.y); // == 180
```

Comment: I noticed the north point is -90, what makes me thing it goes from 0 to 180 and then starts counting negative. Anyway you can make it work starting in 0 (north) and count till 359?

https://jsfiddle.net/7js7e90k/6/

Comment: i think you can simply add 180 to the above's output to convert from +/- 180 to 0-359.

Answer (score 0):

The answer becoming 90° for the 270° case is happening because in both cases, the calculation would return a 0 in `A.y - B.y`. What you have to do is to examine the `x` coordinate to see where the point is situated and add 180° to the answer if point B is left to point A